# Why doesn't jquery-ui autocomplete work inside a jstree?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, jstree

I'm trying to use autocomplete inside a jstree but can't figure out why it doesn't work when both bindings are done in document ready.  It works if the autocomplete binding is done after the jstree binding via windows load or a user triggered script.

This is a simplified example of the issue. ([code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LehJd/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jsTree v.1.0 - Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/_docs/syntax/!style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/_docs/!style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/_docs/syntax/!script.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script>
        function autocomplete(element) {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $(element).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body id="demo_body">
<div id="container">

<h1 id="dhead">jsTree v.1.0</h1>
<h1>DEMO</h1>
<div>
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

<h2>Autocomplete inside jsTree</h2>
<div id="description">

<!-- autocomplete inside a tree works when the user adds autocomplete manually -->
<button type="button" onclick="autocomplete('#tagstree')">add autocomplete manually (comment out other autocomplete bindings)</button>

<div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:100px;">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">
            <label for="tagstree">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tagstree" />
            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">
                    <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">
                    <a href="#">Child node 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">
            <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

/* just to demonstrate an autocomplete field by itself works */
   autocomplete('#tags');

/* adding autocomplete on an element in the tree doesn't work */
   autocomplete('#tagstree');

    $("#demo1")
        .jstree({
            "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys"],
            "core" : { "initially_open" : [ "phtml_1" ] }
        })
        .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        });

});

/* autocomplete inside a tree works when it gets added via windows load instead of document ready */
//$(window).load(function () {
//    autocomplete('#tagstree');
//});

</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The normal answer would be
    .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        autocomplete('#tagstree');
    });
but unfortunately the web application I'm working on is building the nodes before the tree container.  So I'm still stuck finding a solution for my situation.

Comment: Answer is available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417631/adding-auto-complete-to-jstree-input-node