# Adding auto complete to jstree input node

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, jstree

I am creating a JsTree which has an input box Node. I want to enable auto-complete for this input box. The application is in angular4, but the file i am using for creating the jstree is a .js file.

```
inst.create_node(obj, {
li_attr : {
                            'class' : 'child-menu listener-menu'
                        },
                        a_attr:{
                            'ondragover' : 'allowDropSR(event,"widgets")',
                            'ondrop' : 'dropSR(event,"widgets")'
                        },
                        text : "<span>Enter Country here</span>"
                    },
                     "last", function(new_node) {
                        new_node.data = {
                                file : true,
                                stopDrilldown : true,
                                hasParent : true
                        };
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            inst.edit(new_node);
                            $('.jstree-rename-input').attr();
                        },0);

                    });
                    $('.widget-list-tab a').tab('show');
                    $('.jstree-clicked').next('ul').find('li:last').find('a').focus();
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would have been to write your own jsTree plugin. You can possibly hook the keydown event of jsTree for edit box to populate your list of items as a autocomplete suggestion and using jQuery UI autocomplete feature.

```
.bind("keydown.jstree", function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" 
    && e.target.className.toLowerCase() === "jstree-rename-input" ) { 
        $(".jstree-rename-input").autocomplete({
            // AJAX can be used for list here
            source: countries
        });
    }
});
```

countries: is the list suggestion.

You can see in more details at https://everyething.com/jsTree-with-AutoComplete-Box

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is exactly what i was looking for.